# Como comparar um a um todos os elementos de dois vetores?

Tags: c++

Tendo dois vetores de `int` do mesmo tamanho, há alguma função nativa da linguagem que compare a posição **`x`** do primeiro vetor com a posição `x` do segundo vetor, fazendo isso para todas as posições gerando um resultado geral?

Por exemplo, questiono se há algo que realize isto de uma maneira mais direta:

```
// vector de int v1 = 5 3 8
// vector de int v2 = 4 1 6

bool less = true;
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < v1->size(); j++) {
  if (v2->at(j) > v1->at(j))
    less = false;
}
```

Pesquisei e li sobre o [*less*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/less/), mas, pelo meu entendimento, ele não parece fazer o que eu citei.

Comment: Não tem nada pronto, tem várias maneiras de fazer isso, mas precisa de um critério claro, não está claro o que deve fazer na pergunta.

Comment: @bigown o exemplo que eu dei seria uma das maneiras de realizar isso se o critério for "um elemento de v2 é menor que um elemento de v1 para todas as posições do vector", né? Além disso, pelo seu comentário, então não há nada pronto que realize algo com esse critério, certo?

Comment: Você já usou essa frase e ela não é clara para definir o problema que está tentando resolver. Dá para interpretá-la de várias formas.

Comment: @bigown me desculpa, mas não sei como ser mais claro. Acredito que você conseguiu entender o que o código da questão faz, né?

Comment: Talvez, mas pode ser a solução errada, se o problema for errado.

Comment: @bigown tentarei explicar novamente utilizando o código na questão. Nesse código, considerando que v1 e v2 tem os valores que estão nos comentários, após a execução do laço a variável "less" terá o valor true, isso porque para cada índice possível (a variável k) o valor de v2 nesse índice é menor que o valor de v1 nesse mesmo índice. Então, "ser menor" seria o critério. Mas enfim, se você acredita que chovi no molhado e repeti agora o que já falei antes, sem problema, pois já considero que você respondeu a minha pergunta no seu primeiro comentário ao dizer que não há nada pronto que faça isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há função nativa que faça isso porque essa comparação não faz sentido *como um recurso de uso geral*. Isto é, você pode ter alguma necessidade para fazer essa comparação, mas um vetor tem uso muito amplo e uma comparação individual de seus números pode ser implementada com diferentes nuances (mais detalhes no final).

A função `less` não faz o que você deseja, embora possa ser utilizada pra te ajudar. Essa função serve para comparar *dois únicos valores/objetos*. Se você olhar no exemplo da própria documentação que referenciou, verá as seguintes chamadas:

```
int foo[]={10,20,5,15,25};
. . .
std::sort (foo, foo+5, std::less<int>()); // 5 10 15 20 25
```

Ou seja, o que a última linha (onde `less` está sendo utilizado) faz é ordenar os elementos em `foo` em ordem crescente. O `less` ali está meramente sendo utilizado como o *comparador*. Você poderia passar outro comparador existente ou criar um próprio para ordenar a lista segundo qualquer outro critério, pois a interface do algoritmo `sort` é justamente criada para tal.

Se a sua intenção por "maneira mais direta" é usar menos código ao fazer a comparação, a melhor forma é realmente sobrecarregar o operador de comparação menor (`operator<`).

Eu refiz o código que você postou em um exemplo completo (aliás, da próxima vez que criar uma pergunta, procure prover o [*exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para facilitar que alguém se interesse em te ajudar) que sobrecarrega esse operador. O código está abaixo e pode ser executado também [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/Q34ooW):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional> // Necessário para usar o std::less

using namespace std;

// Sobrecarrega o operador de menor para a classe `vector`
bool operator<(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator aIt = a.begin();
    vector<int>::const_iterator bIt = b.begin();

    bool ret = true;
    while(aIt != a.end() && bIt != b.end())
    {
        //if(*aIt >= *bIt) // <== Mais simples e mais claro. Portanto, melhor.
        if(!less<int>()(*aIt, *bIt))
        {
            ret = false;
            break;
        }

        ++aIt;
        ++bIt;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1 = {5, 3, 8};
    vector<int> v2 = {4, 1, 6};

    // Imprime os vetores para conferência
    cout << "v1: ";
    for (auto i: v1)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    cout << "v2: ";
    for (auto i: v2)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    // Usa diretamente o operador para verificar se v2 é menor do que v1
    cout << "v2 < v1? " << (v2 < v1 ? "SIM" : "NAO") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Algumas observações finais:

1. Esse código sobrecarrega `operator<` *no escopo global* para a classe `std::vector`, de forma que você passa a poder fazer `v1 < v2` para qualquer vetor de inteiros.
2. Note o uso da função `less` na implementação dessa sobrecarga. Ela funciona, mas é totalmente desnecessária, já que é mais prático e direto simplesmente fazer a comparação você mesmo (linha comentada).
3. No seu código original você tinha uma variável chamada `less`, cujo nome é o mesmo da função `std::less`. **Tome muito cuidado com isso**, pois ao usar o mesmo nome você corre o risco de misturar as referências (a não ser que mantenha o namespace a cada chamada de `std::less` ao invés de apenas `less` - isto é, sem usar o `using namespace std` no começo).
4. Note como a implementação da sobrecarga não usa um índice numérico como na sua implementação original, mas sim dois iteradores (um para cada vetor `a` e `b`). No seu código original, se os vetores tiverem tamanhos diferentes, você corria o risco de ter um acesso inválido ao fazer `v2->at(j)`, já que `j` era incrementado conforme o tamanho de `v1`.

> A minha escolha de implementação garante que o erro mencionado no item
>   4 não aconteça (porque o laço termina quando qualquer um dos
>   iteradores chegar no fim). Porém, em casos em que os vetores tenham
>   tamanhos distintos, a resposta dada vai ser a comparação só da parte
>   inicial do vetor maior, com a mesma quantidade de elementos do vetor
>   menor. Por isso que lá no começo eu disse que essa comparação não faz
>   sentido sempre. Não sabemos qual é o seu problema, nem se os vetores
>   terão sempre o mesmo tamanho. Mas no caso de tamanhos diferentes, vale
>   dizer que `v2` é menor do que `v1` mesmo que `v2` tenha *mais*
>   elementos do que `v1`? **Ninguém além de você sabe responder a essa
>   questão**.

Comment: Luiz, no seu exemplo você utiliza o namespace `std`, mas dentro dos dois laços no `main` você o apresenta ao invés de ocultá-lo. Há algum motivo para isso?

Comment: Não, motivo nenhum além de eu ter esquecido lá. Desculpe. :) Como eu fiz `using namespace std;` lá no começo, não há necessidade de especificar o namespace ao fazer `std::cout`. Isto é, basta usar `cout` ali nos laços.

Answer (score 1):

É possível fazer a comparação elemento a elemento entre dois vetores (na verdade entre duas sequências quaisquer especificadas por iterators) através do algoritmo "mismatch".

A "função de comparação" é um predicado booleano genérico "bool f(x,y)" que pode ser especificada de várias maneiras, por exemplo uma função, ou um function object, ou uma expressão lambda. Quando não especificada, a função de comparação utilizada é a "igualdade" (isto é, função que compara se dois elementos são iguais).

O algoritmo mismatch retorna um objeto std::pair contendo os iterators (referentes às duas sequências) onde a "comparação" falhou, ou o iterator ".end()" se a "comparação" foi bem sucedida em todos os elementos.

Referência: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch

No exemplo abaixo, o programa vai exibir "(1) all less" quando o algoritmo mismatch for aplicado aos vetores v1 = { 1, 2, 3 } e v2 = { 2, 3, 4 }, e vai exibir "(2) not all less" quando o algoritmo mismatch for aplicado aos vetores v3 = { 1, 2, 3 } e v4 = { 1, 3, 4 }.

```
#include <algorithm> // para mismatch
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<int> v1 { 1, 2, 3 };
   vector<int> v2 { 2, 3, 4 };

   vector<int> v3 { 1, 2, 3 };
   vector<int> v4 { 1, 3, 4 };

   auto result1 = mismatch(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), less<int>());
   if (result1.first == v1.end())
      cout << "(1) all less\n";
   else
      cout << "(1) not all less\n";

   auto result2 = mismatch(v3.begin(), v3.end(), v4.begin(), less<int>());
   if (result2.first == v3.end())
      cout << "(2) all less\n";
   else
      cout << "(2) not all less\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maneira mais direta seria você montar uma função onde você passa como referencia dois vectores com sua regra, retornando ou não valores, ou imprimindo ou não, talvez um `swap()`, ai é com você! segue um exemplo!

```
void compare(vector<int>& vec1, vector<int>& vec2){
    for (int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++){
        if (vec1[i] == vec2[i])
            cout << "os valores da posição :" << i << "são iguais!" << endl;
        if (vec1[i] < vec2[i])
            cout << "o valor("<< vec1[i] <<") do vec1 na posição:" << i << "é menor que o vec2!" << endl;
        else
            cout << "o valor(" << vec2[i] << ") do vec2 na posição:" << i << "é menor que o vec1!" << endl;
    }
}
```